# Proving $\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2\geqslant(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)$ for positive reals $a$, $b$, $c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

**Question $5$ of BMO1 $2008$:**

For positive real numbers $\;a,\;b,\;c,\;$ prove that $$\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2\geqslant(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)$$

I noticed that the right side can be grouped, but did not get further.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding both sides and moving positive terms to their respective sides, we get:

$a^4 +b^4+\dfrac{c^4}{2}\geqslant a^2 c^2 + b^2 c^2$

By AMGM we have:

$a^4 + \dfrac{c^4}{4}\geqslant a^2 c^2\;$ and $\;b^4 + \dfrac{c^4}{4}\geqslant b^2 c^2$

Answer (score 1):

If the right hand side is negative then the inequality trivially holds. Otherwise $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle, and by [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) for the area $S$ of a triangle the inequality reduces to:

$$
a^2+b^2 \ge 4 S
$$

This follows from $S = \frac{1}{2} ab \sin C \le \frac{1}{2} ab$ and the means inequalities $ab \le \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2\le \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] It is not possible for two factors on the right hand side of the original expression to be negative, since for example $a+b-c\lt 0$ and $b+c-a \lt 0$ would imply $b \lt 0$. Therefore, when the right hand side is non-negative each factor must be non-negative, so $a,b,c$ observe the triangle inequalities and must be the sides of a (possibly degenerate) triangle.

Comment: Have you copied from my comment?

Comment: @Angelo I am not *that* quick with editing ;-) But I saw Blue's comment, and thought that was a valid point to be addressed.

Comment: In this case, we have had the same thoughts at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)=((a+b)^2-c^2)(c^2-(a-b)^2)=
\\
=(2ab+a^2+b^2-c^2)(2ab-a^2-b^2+c^2)=(2ab)^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2.
$$
Can you continue now?

Answer (score 0):

And now, a geometric argument.

If any of the terms on the right hand side are nonpositive, the inequality follows trivially. If they are all positive, $a,b,c$ form the legs of a triangle:

[image]

By Heron's formula, the area of this triangle is
$$
\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)}
$$
The area of the triangle is also half the sum of the area of the two rectangles. However, a rectangle with diagonal $d$ can't have more area than $d^2/2$, so the total area of the two rectangles is less than $(a^2 + b^2)/2$. Since the triangle has half this area, we have
$$
\frac{a^2 + b^2}{4} \ge \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)}
$$
Squaring both sides and clearing denominators then gives your inequality.

Comment: *"If any of the terms on the right hand side are nonpositive, the inequality follows trivially."* ... There's a wrinkle: What if *two* of the factors are negative?

Comment: @Blue That situation is impossible for positive reals $a, b, c$.

Comment: If two factor were negative, then at least one of the real numbers $a,b,c$ would be negative too, but it is impossible for hypothesis. For example, if $a+b-c<0$ and $b+c-a<0$, then $b<0.$

Comment: @eyeballfrog: *"That situation is impossible for positive reals $a$, $b$, $c$."* ... I agree. (I've used this property many, many times.) I'm merely suggesting that this may not be immediately obvious to the reader.